# Swift 3 and Firebase Observe Child if it exist

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Need to observe a node in my **Firebase Database** if it exist.
[image]

The code I am using is this:

```
 var COLOR_REF = Database.database().reference().child("Colors")

self.COLOR_REF.child(id).observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
                let key = snapshot.key
                Api.Post.getMyPosts(withId: key, completion: { (post) in
                    completion(post)
                })
            }
```

The id might or might not exist...
What I need is to perform the observation

```
  if child(id) exist else do something else.
```

Is there a way to do so in a single observation or I need to observe `COLOR_REF` and then if the id exist observe the child?

Thank you!
----------------------------- UPDATE
Based on the picture lets say my id is:

D7CGNLehdjksnjkdsiwgqauymj3
i perform the observation like this:

```
COLOR_REF.child(id).observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
if snapshot.exists() {
print("YES")
} else {
print("No")
}
 let key = snapshot.key
  Api.Post.getMyPosts(withId: key, completion: { (post) in
  completion(post)
     })
   }
```

so assumed that id when i perform the observe the console does not print either "YES" nor "NO". So basically it seems never to enter in the observer

-----------------------------SECOND UPDATE
Here's how I am doing it now:

```
func observeFeed(withUserId id: String, completion: @escaping (Post) -> Void, isEmpty: @escaping () -> Void) {
    COLORS_REF.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
        if snapshot.hasChild(id) {
            self.COLORS_REF.child(id).observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
                let key = snapshot.key
                Api.Post.getMyPosts(withId: key, completion: { (post) in
                    completion(post)
                })
            }
        } else {
            isEmpty()
        }
    }
}
```

Like this is working... i do store everything in an array upon completion. My issue is that if it is the first time a user log in that part of the database will be empty.
So i was wondering if there is a way to achieve this without having to use a double observer...

Answer (score 0):

You can check if an id exists by checking if the snapshot.exists() returns true or false on an observe like this:

```
    self.COLOR_REF.child(id).observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
            if snapshot.exists() {
               //the id is valid
            }
            else {
                //the id is not there. do something else
             }

    }) { (error) in

        print(error.localizedDescription)

        //snapshot might have been nil, or there was no id or security rules denied permission to read. do something else.

    }
```

Comment: I tried like this... but if the id does not exist id does not give me any snapshot..

Comment: It should return true or false for snapshot.exists(). If not, try and add the cancelBlock after the Firebase observe. I have updated my answer to show this. If the snapshot returns nil, it should enter the cancel block and you know there was no id.

Comment: It never enters the cancelBlock, because there are actually no errors... the problem is that it never triggers the observer because the child(id) does not exists...

Comment: @Marco you discover how to know if child exists??

Answer (score 0):

Like this are you asking ? Firebase itself provide a default function to check after handler execution that the snapshot is empty or not ?

```
self.COLOR_REF.child(id).observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in

if snapshot.exists(){
    //id exists
    let key = snapshot.key
    Api.Post.getMyPosts(withId: key, completion: { (post) in
        completion(post)
    })
}
else{
    //id do not exists
}

}
```

Reupdate - Answer

As in you want to check id exist in DB or not can manage in two ways

1) Get all id Number offline in array when you load app or any place and use that array for checks 
2) need to make use of two handlers in that case when first handler is satisfied enter in second

Need code I will design that for second option

Update Answer -

How about managing a Value in database about isDatabaseEmpty as Bool or string

Sp DB to be like

```
----Root
  ---UserID
    --isDatabaseEmpty : "True" // if first time user and "False" //if db has values
      --Colors
        -Value1
        -Value2

  ---UserID
    --isDatabaseEmpty : "True" // if first time user and "False" //if db has values
      --Colors
        -Value1
        -Value2
```

And now check isDatabaseEmpty if False Go to second handler else no, 
Will it help ?

Comment: That's what i was trying... but it seems to have not snapshot if the id does not exist in the database...

Comment: this is what you want , here if after handler execution if snapshot turns out to be nil , that means the id you looked is not in DB ? or I am getting you wrong something else you are looking for ?

Comment: as in if id do not exist Obviously no snapshot value will be returned and you need to manage you tableView or collectionView with it , yes in case if you need a data while a id does not exists you can pass some static data in else case

Comment: no that would be perfect.... but it seems not to enter the observe at all if the child is not there... if i do: COLORS_REF.child(id).observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
                    print("Here")

Comment: so you want a check on DB before entering handler ? that Your id exist for not ?

Comment: I think such check is not required just use same check and show a toast or alert when snapshot is nil and do not load your views till that. as in without looking at db using handler you can not manage id existence if you want you had to keep some of data offline as get All id Numberl at your app first load in array and use check there save time

Comment: please check answer

Comment: updated my question...i store all ids in array upon observation

Comment: Updated my answer Check please if it helps

Comment: The database structure is a bit complex.... it's a social I'm building so i have a node users with all the user's informations and then others nodes... one of this node is Color which store the id of the user and inside the id of the colors. It might be that a user has not saved any colors yet and so the tableview will be empty. So when observing the child id the observer is never triggered and i don't know how to display a message in the tableView just in the case this is empty...

Comment: isDatabaseEmpty you just need to check once and don't need it every time , it is just used to know weather the userID has a value or not , will add one line of code for check and get you expected output. in case its not suitable to you I will try think of other option

Comment: I honestly i did not understand where to put it... in Colors Node? and update it in case it removes all colors?

Comment: I think the problem is the .childAdded... if i use value it works the if snapshot.exists(). Issue is that i need to observe when a color is added...

Comment: I've posted and answer... that is the only way i could think to fix it...

Answer (score 0):

The only way i Could fix is like this:

```
func observeFeed(withUserId id: String, completion: @escaping (Post) -> Void, isEmpty: @escaping () -> Void) {
    COLOR_REF.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        if !snapshot.hasChild(id) {
            isEmpty()
            return
        }
    }
   COLOR_REF.child(id).observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
        let key = snapshot.key
        Api.Post.getMyPosts(withId: key, completion: { (post) in
            completion(post)
        })
    }
}
```